# Colorize Layers in Inkscape

Tags: diagram, inkscape

I need to draw a diagram with different colors. Therefore I would like to have one layer per color.

When I add a layer that contains only a rectangular filled with a color above a layer with a white drawing on a black background. Then I can use the "Blend mode" multiply and the white drawing is colorized.

Is it also possible to just colorize everything in a layer that is black?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there'll be any GUI-based solution lighter than the one you have.

But since you are in StackOverflow, you can probably code. Then you could use a script with a text file parser (such as `sed`) to modify the colour of desired elements in the `svg` file.

Comment: is there a way to simply write such a function inside of inkscape?